# Are global variables stored in browser after the processing is ended?

Tags: javascript

Please see the following code.
After I clicked the button "PUT VAR", the alert always shows me the value "putted!!" when I click the button "SHOW VAR".
Does this mean that I can use global variables as hidden values on the page?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var test_var = "default";
$(function(){
    $("#show_var").on("click", function(){
        alert(test_var);
    });

    $("#put_var").on("click", function(){
        test_var="putted!!";
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo">
<input type="button" value="SHOW VAR" style="width:100px" id="show_var" />
<input type="button" value="PUT VAR" style="width:100px" id="put_var" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are stored as long as the context in which they were created is valid. Essentially

```
var test_var = value
```

outside of any closure is the same as

```
window.test_var = value.
```

The `window` object gets destroyed after a `unload` event, so as long as you stay in the same document context your variables are stored.

So, yes, you can use them as *hidden values*, but you should use `<input type="hidden">` for form values.

Comment: Should I use <input type="hidden"> because of the conflict of variables or anything?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" value="myValue">` is a form element. As such it won't be disabled if you disable JavaScript. This is only important for forms. If you want to share JavaScript variables, which don't take part in any forms, feel free to declare them in your JS code.